# (Unity) Network manager work in playMode but not in real android device

Tags: c#, networking, monodevelop

I create this code to send email to gmail account using unity, this code work fine in the playMode of unity also in windows version but not in my real android device, this is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class email : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text txt;
    string i="success";
    public void send(string i)
    {


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage ();
            mail.From = new MailAddress ("Myemail@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add ("receiver_mail@gmail.com");

            mail.Body = i;
            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient ("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtpServer.Port = 587;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential ("Myemail@gmail.com", "Password") as ICredentialsByHost;
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
            delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
                return true;
            };
            smtpServer.Send (mail);
        Debug.Log ("seccess");
        TextSucces ();



    }
    IEnumerator waiting(){
        foreach (char k in i.ToCharArray()) {
        txt.text += k;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

    }
}
    public void TextSucces(){
        txt.text = "";
        StartCoroutine ("waiting");
    }
}
```

when i run my project and click a button in the scene i send an email and i get

> success in console

Comment: does your android have an active internet connection?

Comment: yes of course i think i messing some configuration in my project